# Unhandled exception: Unsupported operation: serialization of generic DartType: UnknownType(?) (UnknownType)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I keep getting this error

`Unhandled exception: Unsupported operation: serialization of generic DartType: UnknownType(?) (UnknownType)`

everytime i try to run my project.
I run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` and I get `pub finished with exit code 78`

> /// Something was unconfigured or mis-configured.
> const CONFIG = 78;

> This is likely because the`.dart_tool/build` folder was deleted, or you are submitting generated files to your source repository.
> [SEVERE] Conflicting outputs were detected and the build is unable to prompt for permission to remove them. These outputs must be removed manually or the build can be run with `--delete-conflicting-outputs

I then proceed to run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` and get

> [INFO] Succeeded after 49.5s with 14 outputs (227 actions)

and on runnning my app we I get `the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by adding a `build.yaml`
configs:

```
    targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          # Options configure how source code is generated for every
          # `@JsonSerializable`-annotated class in the package.
          #
          # The default value for each is listed.
          any_map: false
          checked: false
          create_factory: true
          create_to_json: true
          disallow_unrecognized_keys: false
          explicit_to_json: false
          field_rename: none
          ignore_unannotated: false
          include_if_null: true
          nullable: true
```

> [INFO] Succeeded after 199ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)